# MYSQL only Show columns which allow null

Tags: mysql, null

I need to be able to pull the column names which allow a NULL value,  I know that

```
show columns from TABLE
```

Will give show me the table properties and whether or not the column allows null values, but is there a way to just return ONLY the columnnames which allow null.

`show columns from TABLE where Null = 'YES'` doesn't work, but it explains what I need to accomplish.

And of course it's easy to just pull everything and sort it out later on, but if there IS a way to do what I'm asking, I'd like to learn it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes you can do it by using the information_schema database..

use the Query

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME 
FROM information_schema.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='db name' 
  AND TABLE_NAME='table Name' 
  AND IS_NULLABLE='YES';
```

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT table_schema, table_name, column_name
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE IS_NULLABLE = 'Yes'
```

Run describe on information_schema.columns to refine the results to your liking

Answer (score 1):

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM `table_name` WHERE `Null` = 'YES'
```

Above query works. Try to avoid querying to `information_schema` directly

Comment: The problem is that you have to use backticks around Null, but you don't have to use it with other column names (unless they contain a space), like Field and Type. Even the MySQL Reference Manual use an example without backticks, but they don't mention the special case with Null, so someone might make them aware of that.

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-columns.html and https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/extended-show.html